# Android dialog pass touches to parent window

Tags: android

How can I pass the touch from android dialog to parent window. I have tried to make a customDialog to say

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

but it didn't help

Comment: as I know, super is not the parent window, it is the parent class. I guess you could try to get a parent reference then call it.